# Why is there a message in my analytics.google (Google Analytics 4) which says Data collection isn’t active for my demo website?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-api

I have created a demo stream in https://analytics.google.com/.
[image]

Next in [tag manager](https://tagmanager.google.com/)
I created a Google Tag Manager account, a container and a new tag with relative trigger .
Next I published my container.
I Installed the Google tag manually by pasting provided script:[image: script for Google Tag]
I copied the script provided in workspace of tag manager, and paste them after Google Tag script and the second script as mentioned in photo in body:
[image: scripts of Google tag]

in `DebugView` page of `analytics.google` and `tagassistant.google` I can see all the information which seems to be correct. however, why in the first picture I have the highlighted yellow message? If I click the button `View Tag Instructions`, it only shows the script I have already copied in my pages.

Comment: did you find a resolution? I have this same banner appearing even though my tag assistant and dataLayer are populating

Comment: @jimmyNames yes, but do not remember what was the problem, anyway, you can create a new question explain what exactly you did and mention here your question link, I will check it out